# How do I get an object in Unity to move down the Y-axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

```
public GameObject enemyfireball;


void Update()
{
    enemyfireball.transform.position += -transform.up * Time.deltaTime * 5f;
}
```

I am not sure how to make this work in a different way, the object just won't move. For reference this is for a 2D game.

Comment: Try use `+= Vector2.down` instead of `+- -transform.up`?

Comment: @Daevin used Vector2.down and it gave me a error: "Assets/Scripts/EnemyFireball.cs(27,9): error CS0034: Operator '+=' is ambiguous on operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector2' ''

Answer (score 1):

transform is local, so transform.up is up to what object this script is on. Try using Vector3.down (or Vector3.up).

Something like

```
public GameObject enemyfireball;


void Update()
{
    enemyfireball.transform.position += Vector2.down * Time.deltaTime * 5f;
}
```

Comment: They mentioned it's a 2D game (and you wrote "Vectro" :P) so it should probably say `Vector2`.

Comment: I get no compilation errors, but the object still does not work.

Comment: @BenjaminMoralesPerez do you have this script attached to the `GameObject`? In the `Update` method, put `Debug.Log(enemyfireball.transform.position);` and see if it's writing in the Unity console.

Comment: @BenjaminMoralesPerez what is not working? can you describe it?